# Recursive Facebook API Call

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Basically this is what I want to do

```
- Get all my likes (page likes)
- Get all my friends
- for each of my friends, get their likes
- for each of their likes, do something
```

Now, the way I'm doing this is by using JS SDK, because I've tried PHP SDK and it's really slow (so slow that PHP error of maximum execution time kicks in), is PHP SDK always slower than JS? My script is something like this :

```
var newArray = [];
FB.api('me/likes', function(response){
   FB.api('me/friends', function(friends){
       $(friends).each(function(){
           FB.api(this.uid+'/likes', function(fr_likes){
             $(fr_likes).each(function(){
               //save this friend likes to newArray
               newArray.push(this);
             });
           });
       });
   });
});

//call newArray outside FB scope doesn't work at first
console.log(newArray);  //returns [] / empty
```

But if I use chrome console to call newArray after awhile, newArray is slowly populated with FB data.

So my question is :

1. Can I wait for all the FB.api calls to be complete before doing something outside FB scope?
2. What is the best practice for doing something like that (recursive FB api calls)?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).  It allows you to make multiple requests in one single round-trip to Facebook's servers.  Should speed things up considerably.